# ELO in Super Smash Bros. Melee

Tags: terminology, super-smash-bros-melee

I see a lot of people talking about ELO in Smash, (bronze, gold, plat, etc.) but I never understood what it meant. Does anyone have any answers on how to get an ELO? Like is there a competitive scene I haven't found yet? If someone could tell me it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I also had no idea what ELO meant, having played Melee since day 1. But doing a small google search, I found this [reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/76cpy8/ranking_the_top_melee_players_using_elo/). It also links a wiki article on what the "Elo" rating system actually is. Not sure if this is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The ranking system they are most likely referring to is [Smashladder](https://www.smashladder.com/), an online community that uses the Dolphin emulator to run matches.